# Value from optional binding out of scope?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm a Designer feeling my way through some basic swift and just getting stuck on basic programming stuff.  The function opens a local json file and gets the 'version' value and return it as a double.  That works, but I can't seem to access the data outside of the optional binding? Inside the scope of the "if let" statement the data is correct, but when I try to do the final return it is always nil.

```
func getLocalVersionNumber() -> Double {

var localVersion: Double!

if let file = NSBundle(forClass:AppDelegate.self).pathForResource("localdata", ofType: "json") {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: file)!
    let localData = JSON(data:data)

    if localData != nil {

        if let version = localData[0]["version"].double {

            var localVersion: Double = version
            // at this point I can print to the console and it's correct

        } else {
            localVersion = 3.1
        }
    }
}
return localVersion!
}
```

I'm sure this has been answered a bunch of times, but being new, I don't really know what I should be searching for as I don't know all of the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-declaring localVersion inside if the `if let`.

So, instead of:

```
if let version = localData[0]["version"].double {
    var localVersion: Double = version
} else {
    localVersion = 3.1
}
```

try

```
if let version = localData[0]["version"].double {
    localVersion = version
} else {
    localVersion = 3.1
}
```

Comment: :)  Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.